# Can we pass html log path in pytest from a variable in script

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to `pytest`. I am looking for a way to generate html logging in pytest. I got one way which is generating html logs too like

```
pytest script.py--html=report.html
```

It is working. But the problem is the html report path. Can I provide html path in a var that is present in the script?

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code i think this might help

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to generate the HTML report without entering the `--html` argument every time, you can persist it in the config file. Create a file named `pytest.ini` with the content:

```
[pytest]
addopts=--html my_report.html
```

Now running `pytest` will always generate the HTML report in `my_report.html` file.

However, if you want to have a dynamic name that is set from code, you need to overwrite the `config.option.htmlpath` attribute. Create a file `conftest.py` in the root dir and add the `pytest_configure` hook there:

```
import pytest


default_html_path = 'my_report.html'

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    if not config.option.htmlpath:
        config.option.htmlpath = default_html_path
```

`pytest_configure` is a hook that will run before the tests start. When no `--html` argument was supplied from command line (the `if` check), the html report file path will be set to the value of `default_html_path` variable. If you need dynamic resolution of the report name, do it there.

Answer (score 1):

After check you code, you use the `pytest-html` tool for generate the HTML format report.
At the `pytest-html` just follow the path like that：

```
pytest .\Desktop\demo.py --html=F:\tmp\report.html
```

[image]

the pytest-html not support the pass html path from script.

You can try the `pytest-cov`, it can config the html path through a `.coveragerc` file.

http://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html
Configuration
This plugin provides a clean minimal set of command line options that are added to pytest. For further control of coverage use a coverage config file.

For example if tests are contained within the directory tree being measured the tests may be excluded if desired by using a .coveragerc file with the omit option set:

```
py.test --cov-config .coveragerc
        --cov=myproj
        myproj/tests/
```

Where the .coveragerc file contains file globs:

```
[run]
omit = tests/*
```

For full details refer to the coverage config file documentation.

https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html

**`[html]`**

Values particular to HTML reporting. The values in the `[report]` section also apply to HTML output, where appropriate.

`directory` (string, default “htmlcov”): where to write the HTML report files.

`extra_css` (string): the path to a file of CSS to apply to the HTML report. The file will be copied into the HTML output directory. Don’t name it “style.css”. This CSS is in addition to the CSS normally used, though you can overwrite as many of the rules as you like.

`title` (string, default “Coverage report”): the title to use for the report. Note this is text, not HTML.

Comment: Can I pass this html path from script instead of giving it in commandline

Comment: @Nitesh,  the pytest-html not support the pass html path from script.

Comment: Is there some hack for this ?

Comment: @Nitesh  you can the `pytest-cov` .

Comment: Will try this .Thanks. pytest is so vast, Its like I am lost in the waves of pytest